# SQL Student Database

Tags: sql, count

I am having a hard time trying to display the number of classes in a column a student is taking.

I have the following query but I am not sure if what exactly the COUNT is counting and how to display the count for each student:

```
CREATE VIEW Busy_Student AS
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Student.Student_ID
FROM Student 
INNER JOIN Enrollment ON Enrollment.Student_ID= Student.Student_ID
GROUP BY Student.Student_ID, Student.First_Name, Student.Last_Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Create a view call BUSY_STUDENT that stores the concatenated name (first name and last name), student id and count of classes enrolled in, for all students enrolled in more than 2 classes.  Name the columns, FULL_NAME, STUDENT_ID and ENROLL_NUM respectively.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add a tag for the DBMS you're using (concatenation operators vary between them) and some information on your table definitions? As it is, though, your `SELECT` does nothing to provide the "concatenated name", as you're not concatenating them (combining first and last name into a single "first_name last_name" column, usually given an aliased name like "student_name" or "full_name"), and if you're going to show the "count of classes enrolled" you need to add the `COUNT(*)` to your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @anakata: "be more clear" about what? If you're going to comment on the question, please *be more clear* about what you're asking the person to explain more clearly. Your comment serves no purpose if you don't explain what they need to "be more clear" about in the question.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not trying to defend myself here, but I was asking the OP to be more clear because I couldn't understand the question at all! really! but now looking at the answers (and you) I'm realizing that that was my problem!. Anyway, I will try to be *more clear* when asking for clarification xD

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement should be something like this:

```
SELECT First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS [FULL_NAME],
Student.Student_ID, COUNT(*) AS [ENROL_NUM]
FROM Student 
INNER JOIN Enrollment ON Enrollment.Student_ID= Student.Student_ID
GROUP BY Student.Student_ID, Student.First_Name, Student.Last_Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close to it:

```
CREATE VIEW Busy_Student AS
SELECT
    CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name) AS FULL_NAME,
    Student.Student_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
    COUNT(Enrollment.Enrollment_id) AS ENROLL_NUM
FROM Student 
INNER JOIN Enrollment USING(Student_ID)
GROUP BY Student.Student_ID
HAVING ENROLL_NUM > 2
```

The count is done on the number of `Enrollment` rows matching the student id. Since you only gave the inner join column, I made the supposition that each each enrollment was uniquely identified by the column `Enrollment_id`. You should adjust that column name according to your schema.

Use

```
First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS FULL_NAME
```

for SQL Server.